# Best way to change type of column in dynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the DynamoDB table that is filled from different services/sources. The table has next schema:

```
{
  "Id": 14782,
  "ExtId": 1478240974, //pay attention it is Number
  "Name": "name1"
}
```

Sometimes, after services started to work I had found that one service sends data in incorrect format. It looks like:

```
{
  "Id": 14782,
  "ExtId": "1478240974", //pay attention it is String
  "Name": "name1"
}
```

DynamoDB is NoSQL database so, now I have millions mixed records that are difficult to query or scan. I understand that my main fault was missed validation.

Now I have to go throw all records and if it is inappropriate type - remove it and add with same data but with the correct format. Is it possible to do in another gracefully way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it was pretty easy. It is possible to do with `attribute_type` method.

First of all, I added imports:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
import boto3
```

And my code:

```
    attr = Attr('ExtId').attribute_type('S')
    response = table.scan(FilterExpression = attr)
    items = response['Items']

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(FilterExpression = attr, ExclusiveStartKey = response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        items.extend(response['Items'])
```

It is possible to find more condition customization in the next article - [DynamoDB Customization Reference](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html)